# jQuery: why the wrap() doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

I have looked on StackOverflow and came across a few other similar issues but I can't figure out why my simple `wrap()` function doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
var createImage = function (url) {
  return $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
    var $img = $('<img class="imgs">');
    var caption = $('.note-image-caption').val();
    var credit = $('.note-image-credit').val();

    //alert(caption);

    $img.one('load', function () {
      $img.off('error abort');
      deferred.resolve($img);
    }).one('error abort', function () {
      $img.off('load').detach();
      deferred.reject($img);
    }).css({
      display: 'none'
    }).appendTo(document.body).attr('src', url);

    $( ".imgs:last" ).css( 'border', 'solid 10px red');

    $( ".imgs:last" ).wrap( '<div class="cont"></div>');


  }).promise();
};
```

At first I thought the issue was that my code couldn't fine the last element but i tried the following test which showed that the `last:` is working fine. So i don't really understand why the `wrap()` doesn't work.

This works fine:

```
$( ".imgs:last" ).css( 'border', 'solid 10px red');
```

But this doesn't:

```
$( ".imgs:last" ).wrap( '<div class="cont"></div>');
```

I also, looked in the console to see if there is nay error and there is none.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Just because someone asked to provide the HTML, this is how the html looks like. Please note that the  tags are created dynamically:

```
<p><img class="imgs" src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/aaed60690d01451a9c5a31c4874813a8.png"></p>

<p><img class="imgs" src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/aaed60690d01451a9c5a31c4874813a8.png"></p>

<p><img class="imgs" src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/aaed60690d01451a9c5a31c4874813a8.png"></p>
```

I also tried this and still doesn't work:

```
$( "p .imgs" ).wrap( '<div class="cont"></div>');
```

**Strange thing just happened now:**

I added this to my code: `$( ".cont" ).css( 'border', 'solid 10px blue');`

and when i tested my code, I saw that the div `.cont` is created but not around the `.imgs`! So its just empty and its not wrapped around the img. in fact its being appended to the bottom of the page right before the  tag!!

Third EDIT:

Here is a working FIDDLE AS REQUESTED:

https://jsfiddle.net/8qcrrcb7/

Please click on the Picture button and use this URL to add an image to the content editor:

*`http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/aaed60690d01451a9c5a31c4874813a8.png`*

and you will see the issue there too.
as you can see the div `.cont` is created but its not wrapped around the `.imgs`.

I'm getting close but I still have an issue which I don't have a clue how to fix.

**EDIT:**

I now changed my code to this:

```
$('.note-editable .imgs:last').wrap( '<div class="cont"></div>');
$( ".cont" ).css( 'border', 'solid 10px blue');
```

This code works BUT it doesn't work for the first .imgs added! So basically it works from the second .imgs +.

This is the fiddle:

**Please look at the lines 3152 and 3153**

https://jsfiddle.net/8qcrrcb7/1/

Comment: Post your html.

Comment: @gaganshera, what html? do you mean the <img> ? if so, that is created dynamically as you can see in the code i posted.

Comment: why don't you warp the img before you append it to the page?

Comment: @madalinivascu, I tried that but I couldn't come up with a good solution.

Comment: Did you try with `$img.last()` instead of  `$(".imgs:last")` ?

Comment: What will happen after adding 'cont' class? Does it have css?

Comment: @VandolphReyes, no, it doesn't have any css.

Comment: This sounds like your HTML may be invalid. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: @Liam, added a working Fiddle.

Comment: Not exactly minimal....? You need to narrow down your problem. What your asking for here is *please debug my code for me*

Comment: @Liam, that is the exact reason that I didn't provide the full code in the first place because I've already provided the "minimal" code to start with and apparently wasn't enough so I provided the full working code. and no, I'm not asking to debug my code. otherwise I would've provided the full code from the get go ;)

Comment: @Liam, and also the main reason that I provided the full working code with minimal HTML is because you did say that the issue is from an invalid HTML which is not true in this case since there is not much HTML used really.

Comment: you're... putting a div in a paragraph tag. Only [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) can go inside a paragraph tag.

Comment: @KevinB, what?!

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine,

The problem is that you are hiding the image, make it display as a block and you can see it.

```
.css({
   display: 'none'
})
```

[image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/surudoiryu/7resn05s/)

Comment: No, that is not the issue because this works fine: $( ".imgs:last" ).css( 'border', 'solid 10px red'); without making the image block.

Comment: When i change it back i wont even see the border.
Are you doing something else on a different part of your code ? 
As you can see by the fiddle it holds your code and it works.

I assume you are using jquery a newer version then 1.4 ?

Comment: I am not doing anything else in my code regarding the images. and yes, i am using jquery 2.1.4

Comment: How are you calling the createImage function?

Comment: Like this:  `return {
      readFileAsDataURL: readFileAsDataURL,
      createImage: createImage
    };`

Comment: I've added a working FIDDLE to my question which should explain the issue better.

Comment: Which linenumbers do i need to look at ?  7K lines are a bit to much to quickly go through.

Comment: 3154 is the line number

Comment: You will have to modify the whole core, as it inserts nodes now like an image node, you cannot. If you do not like to go down that road you could add a class to the image so selecting and changing it after it is inserted easier. Todo this change line 3150 to: `}).appendTo(document.body).attr('class', 'cont').attr('src', url);`